# Apache crashing and stopped working

Tags: apache

**EDIT: NEW ERROR:** `[Fri Apr 10 00:31:01.708007 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4720:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name` And yes the old one is still there.. just this now happens after it has crashed and I have started apache again..

I have recently installed xampp 4 times and each of them times it has been on a fresh installation of windows. With nothing but **dropbox** , **notepad++** , and **xampp** it self installed on the system. I have tried everything to resolve it and below is a list of things I have tried

Running the control panel as administrator
Turning off the windows firewall
Trying it on a fresh installation of windows

Something else you may need to know is I have changed the htdocs location to C:\Dropbox\Website into the dropbox website folder inside the dropbox folder. I have also tried changing the 443 port to 444 but I can't change the 80 to 8080 because it would mean doing my ip then :8080 on the end which I can't do on cloudflare. The error log is always the same when it has crashed and displays the exact same things... Before it did display something about Threads per child and I did change it, but still no luck... after doing it on a new fresh copy of windows its still crashing but with a different error.

```
[Fri Apr 10 00:10:10.818359 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4492:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Apr 10 00:10:10.982421 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4492:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Apr 10 00:10:11.051757 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4492:tid 272] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

That's not all the error log, but thats what keeps ending up in there once its crashed all the time.

Comment: So you are having trouble with the SSL certificate. Did you correctly generate your certificate?

Comment: I don't even know what that means, can you give me a bit more information on that?

Comment: That error is related to port 443 which is the Secured Socket Layer (SSL) port. Are you using SSL on your application?

Comment: Not that I know of because I don't even know what SSL is... I'm pretty sure its https:/ not http:// but I always use http:// I am pretty sure enless one of my visitors are using a different..

Comment: Go to C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra and find the file called http-ssl.conf. Do a contrl-f to find example.com. Copy that section of code so that I can take a look

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Mk8GN2du

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this and your problem might get fixed:

On the file you uploaded:

1. Search for  and replace it with
2. Search for ServerName www.example.com:443 and replace it with ServerName www.example.com

Let me know if this works. I hope this helps.

Comment: I've just made the changed. I will let you know in around 30 minutes if it has fixed it.

Comment: Workd perfectly now, a whole day without a crash thanks!

Comment: No problem. If possible, can you like my answer so people know it is correct?